# Error (403 Forbidden) when calling Graph Api from powershell

Tags: powershell, api, graph

I'm trying to call Graph API from PowerShell using Invoke-RestMethod to get a list of Groups.
    I registered my application. I have the secret string. I added Graph permissions. When I do the call
    I always get the 403 Forbidden error. I probably missing some some other configuration, but I can 
    figure out what is it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Here is how I configured Microsoft Graph permissions:
API / Permissions name      Type        Admin Consent
Group.Read.All          Application     Yes
Group.ReadWrite.All     Application     Yes
Group.Selected          Application     Yes


Here is how I make the call:

$token = Get-PnPAccessToken
$Header = @{
   'Content-Type'  = 'application\json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $token
}
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $Header -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json'
```

> Error message that I'm getting:  Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: 403 means the server knows who you are (aka you are authenticated) but you don't have access to whatever resource you are requesting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm trying to retrieve a list of Groups/Teams. I have admin privileges. I should have access to all resources. Is there something I'm missing in Azure config?

Comment: I figure out the problem. Azure App permission require also
Directory.ReadWrite.All with type Application.